# LVDS inputs and TTL outputs in design

Tags: fpga, ttl, port, vivado, lvds

I have a design and most of the entry ports are the outputs of an ADC these outputs are LVDS.

My question is how do i declare the inputs of my FPGA as LVDS signals?
And how to declare the outputs has TTL
For the moments in the design i just declared the inputs and outputs as std_logic_vector.

I don't know if the LVDS declaration has to be done in the syntesis step or the implementation? is it in a constraint file that it is done?[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, its usually (almost always) in the constraint file. The synthesis tool will take two pins and assign them to a single std_logic bit of a top-level port. Downvoting because, again, your question lacks the proper details that allow a complete answer to be written. No mention of FPGA, FPGA vendor, synthesis software, synthesis software version number and more.

Answer (score 1):

std_logic_vector is internal logic.

The way that becomes 3.3v TTL or LVDS is vendor specific. The I/O blocks have to be configured to use the appropriate drive levels or thresholds.

Read the vendor documentation for your specific part, and it will tell you where to put the configuration information.